# Error referencing my TypeScript modules TS2307: Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, gulp, aurelia, gulp-watch

I am working with the `aurelia-typescript-skeleton` as the base for my new project. I tried adding a new `hello.ts` file in `src` folder

```
export class Hello {
  sayHello(name:string) : string {
    return 'Hello ' + name;
  }
}
```

and referenced it in another file in the same folder as below

```
import {Hello} from './hello';

export class Users {
  constructor() {
    console.log(new Hello().sayHello('Test'));
  }
}
```

Both the files are at the same folder level. Everything works fine when I build for the first time. When I make any subsequent changes on the `users.ts` file, the `gulp-typescript` compilation keeps failing with an error I am unable to understand. The error from the typescript compiler is

```
> Starting 'build-system'...
> src\users.ts(4,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'hello'.
> TypeScript: 1 semantic error
> TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
> Finished 'build-system' after 950 ms
```

Whenever i do a fresh `gulp watch`, there are no errors. The error appears when I edit/change the `users.ts` file. Can anyone help me understand this error? It must be something basic...

I'm on Windows 7 environment, and I get this error on 2 machines.

UPDATE:

Here is the [repo to reproduce the problem](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/skeleton-navigation-typescript). Steps to reproduce:

1. Clone the repo, install all `npm` and `jspm` dependencies.
2. Run `gulp watch` -> no errors occur for me
3. Change `users.ts` file and save -> the error occurs.

UPDATE2:

Adding a `clean` step before `build-system` helps to avoid the problem. Here is [the link to commit](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/skeleton-navigation-typescript/commit/2a12801280e1666a4046528a5a9881f95a3a6bd2). Still I'm not sure about the actual reason of the problem at first hand.

Comment: Please add the error message from gulp too.

Comment: @MartinVseticka See the console output in the question - that's what I get from the gulp task

Comment: I tried to download the repo and install it [ubuntu 15.10]. The build script seems to work for me. I just had to replace `/aurelia-typescript-skeleton/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/fetch-client@0.1.1/aurelia-fetch-client.d.ts` (it contained errors) with some fixes: https://pastee.org/v5ghs My `gulp watch` output: https://pastee.org/pzskc

Comment: @MartinVseticka I'm on Windows, can it make a difference? My output is similar to yours for the first run, but it fails on 2nd and subsequent runs. Tested on 2 machines with same result.

Comment: It's very hard to tell. I know that gulp-typescript and its incremental compilation works on Windows (we have the feature on a different project). So I'm inclined to tell, it should work on Windows. I would try to ask here https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss

Comment: @MartinVseticka Updated the question with repo and steps to reproduce. Do you have Windows to try it? My colleague already asked on gitter, I'll post the link to SO too. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't. But I'll try your repo on my Linux box once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99929/discussion-between-martin-vseticka-and-mikhail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because only `users.ts`, the changed file, is sent to subsequent TS compilation, while `noResolve` is enabled (in `tsconfig.json`).

Please see file `build/tasks/build.js`, task `'build-system'`:

```
.pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.js'}))
```

What files are changed are determined (by `gulp-changed`) by comparing last modified time of the input files with the destination. So when you run `clean` or `watch`, which involve `clean`, the destination is cleaned and all the files are sent to compilation again, thus no error.

As I try the updated skeleton app (1.0.0-beta.1.2.2), this problem has been fixed.

Comment: So, isn't the compiler able to compile just one file? (and kind of be smart to resolve dependencies) Why did it work on ubuntu?

Comment: TS indeed has compile-time [module resolution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Module%20Resolution.md). But since noResolve is enabled, the resolved files are NOT automatically included in compilation.